# How to configure magento2 cron with mamp

Tags: magento2, cron, mamp

I followed the tutorial here:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html
and tried configuring the crons with mamp but in readiness check for upgrade it still shows as not working.

In crontab (`sudo crontab -u user -e`) I have:

```
*/1 * * * * php -c /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini /User/magento-2/bin/magento cron:run >> /User/magento-2/var/log/setup.cron.log&
*/1 * * * * php -c /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini /User/magento-2/update/cron.php >> /User/magento-2/var/log/setup.cron.log&
*/1 * * * * php -c /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini /User/magento-2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /User/magento-2/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

I tried with `/usr/bin/php` instead of php but still not working. The path to the php.ini file is the one that the webserver loads with `phpinfo()`. Could it be that the cron is trying to use another php.ini? There are no errors in the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It tuned out that I had to specify the mamp php:

```
*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php -c /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini /Users/magento-2/bin/magento cron:run >> /Users/magento-2/var/log/setup.cron.log&
*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php -c /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini /Users/magento-2/update/cron.php >> /Users/magento-2/var/log/setup.cron.log&
*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin/php -c /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/conf/php.ini /Users/magento-2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /Users/magento-2/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

Full setup instructions: http://claudiucreanga.me/magento/magento2-setup-with-mamp-including-crons.html