# Magento in Xampp server ( localhost ) indexer:reindex

Tags: magento2, indexer

I'm running Magento latest version in my localhost with xampp, it's great. but in admin panel, I see an error

> One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is
> running.

I searching for a solving I get this one

> indexer:reindex

but how I make it with xampp ?? or the localhost??

Comment: MikeMason's answer is correct, but you'd be better off running a VM of an actual linux install.  The magento docs instructions would be a closer match to your environment.

Comment: You could also just set up cron for your local install. This is for MAMP, but the concept should be the same: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109106/how-to-configure-magento2-cron-with-mamp

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Xampp control panel
2. Click on Shell button
3. Exec the command -->  `php C:\xampp\htdocs\XXXXXX\bin\magento indexer:reindex`

Obs: XXXXXX is your site.

Comment: This worked for me. Totally forgot that Xampp comes with Shell ready.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Command Line (Terminal on Mac). In the Terminal, navigate to the folder you have installed Magento and then to the 'bin' folder. Once in that folder, enter the command:

php magento indexer:reindex

Wait for a while until the Terminal has completed processing the command. Refresh the Admin area and the warning should disappear.

Comment: i enter the "php magento indexer:reindex" the command line give me not recognized !!! @mikeMasin

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below process to reindex from command line.

At first please check which drive you have installed xampp. (Ex. C:).
So if you have xampp installed in drive C:

go to command line - type -

cd\

Now you will go to root drive C:

then please type **cd xampp\php**

now you will see your location  C:\xampp\php>

Now type **php C:\xampp\htdocs\XXXX\bin\magento indexer:reindex**

**(where XXXX is your magento folder name)**

Now you can see that indexing is being processed.